# Oracle Apex-Cant find region button despite being defined

Tags: oracle-apex

I have created a page with pre-rendering to fetch rows from employe table using auto dml processing(legacy).
Post this all page items are defined and aligned with respective columns in source.
After this i created 4 region buttons-> create, cancel, delete and save.
I can see all buttons except save.
Save properties-> SQL UPDATE on submit.
Processing->
Get PK
Process row from Employee tabe-> lock row for insert update and delete.

What else do i need to do or where am i going wrong?

Comment: Server side condition is-> item id not null and employeeid (pk) set.

Comment: You will only see the save button when editing a record, vs seeing the create button when opening the page when ID item is null

Comment: Vini, did you still need help with this or did Scott's answer help?

Comment: Fixed on my own 

Answer (score 0):

This question is already answered by its author.

> Fixed on my own  – Vini